# How should a closed WebSocket behave when send is called?

Tags: javascript, websocket

In the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#send()) for `WebSocket.send` it says:

> Exceptions thrown
>   **INVALID_STATE_ERR**
>   The connection is not currently `OPEN`.

An exception is indeed thrown when in `CONNECTING` state, but if the socket is closed (state is `CLOSED`) then I don't get any exception. This happens for all the browsers I've tried.

I've tried reading the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/comms.html#network) but couldn't seem to find anything relevant.

Here's some reproducing code:

1. Clicking **Create** also sends before the socket is open (exception thrown)
2. After socket is open click **Send** (no exception is thrown)
3. Click **Close** and then **Send** (no exception is thrown, this surprises me)

```js
var s = null;

function log(msg) {
    var d = document.createElement('div');
    d.textContent = (new Date().toLocaleTimeString()) +": " + msg;
    document.getElementById('out').appendChild(d);
}

function create() {
    log("Creating");
    s = new WebSocket("wss://echo.websocket.org");
    
    s.onopen = function() { 
        log("Socket opened");
    }    
    s.onmessage = function(e) { 
        log("Got: " + e.data);
    }
    
 send("before open");
}

function send(msg) {
    try { 
        log("Sending: " + msg);
        s.send(msg);
        log("Send didn't throw");
    }
    catch(e) {
        log("Exception: " + e.message);
    }
}

function close() {
    log("Closing");
    s.close();
}

document.getElementById('create').addEventListener('click', create, true);
document.getElementById('send').addEventListener('click', send.bind(null, 'manually'), true);
document.getElementById('close').addEventListener('click', close, true);
```

```html
<button id="create">Create</button> 
<button id="send">Send</button>
<button id="close">Close</button>
<div id="out"/>
```